# How to tell vscode to index the entire project/folder

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, search, ide, sftp

I'm using vs code on a remote location mounted locally via sftp.

It takes a (relatively) long time to do a directory search (`ctrl+shift+f`) or file search (`ctrl+p`) the first time I search for something.

Is there any way to tell code to index the entire project/folder, such that searching can be as fast as if it were done locally?

Comment: (note for outside of the remote context): search is done with ripgrep. I don't know how much indexing / caching there is, but if you properly exclude folders that you don't want to search in, such as build output folders or dependency package folders, then usually things are just fine...